# Awk function to delete row in 21st column with empty field

Tags: awk

I am trying to delete rows which have an empty field on the 21st column. For some reason this code works on other files (less columns) but not this particular one. I've tried converting the file into space separated, comma separated, tab-delimited nothing seems to work.

I've tried these 2 different methods:

awk -F'\t' '$21!=""'

awk -F'\t' '$21{print $0}'

For example here is a smaller version of my tab-delimited file. I would want to remove rows that are "" in the column "Gene"

| "Gene_ID" | "Sample_1" | "Sample_x" | "Sample_19" | "Gene" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "ENSG00000223972" | 12 | 2 | 1 | "DDX11L1" |
| "ENSG00000227232" | 6 | 12 | 45 | "WASH7P" |
| "ENSG00000278267" | 0 | 4 | 542 | "MIR6859-1" |
| "ENSG00000186092" | 4 | 2 | 34 | "OR4F5" |
| "ENSG00000239945" | 7 | 67 | 22 | "" |
| "ENSG00000233750" | 9 | 4356 | 22 | "CICP27" |
| "ENSG00000241599" | 55 | 4 | 55 | "" |

Comment: Don't post graphical representations of your data, post your data. We need a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we have something to test a potential solution against to be able to help you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

this should work, your field is not blank, it's empty quotes.

```
$ awk -F'\t' '$21!="\"\""'
```

or perhaps easier to read

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v empty='""' '$21!=empty'
```